# How to disable custom observer for particular page in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart

I want disable my created custom observer for my created custom listing page in magento2.

Comment: I have created my custom module to show upsell products. And I have display listing for upsell products for cart of first product.

Answer (score 1):

in order to achieve this ( to disable module on particular page ), get module / route name and add your condition i.e :

if you want to get the module of the current observer? You could implement something similar to what :

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper::_getModuleName().
```

**$this->_getModuleName()** would still work, provided your helper class extends **\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper**.

you will find your solution something around this logic.

Comment: I have created my custom module to show upsell products. And I have display listing for upsell products of cart of first product. And this listing will display when user click on checkout link. For that I have created one observer using, with my help of observer I have display first cart product of upsell listing.and redirect on custom url to display that upsell products listing.  if user Want add to cart  product from upsell products listing.i want go to checkout page using checkout link from minicart. But due to my custom created observer I am not able to redirect on checkout page.

Comment: But my problem is that upsell products listing come from my custom module. So how to disable my custom module for that page. Could you please give me example with code.